# Where can I find reference documentation for OpenShift yaml definitions

Tags: openshift

I can find some fragments of openshift yaml definitions in the OpenShift documentation, for example [in this document](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/applications/deployments/deployment-strategies.html)

But where can I find the whole reference documentation of openshift yaml definitions?

Answer (score 1):

The API reference. For example, https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/rest_api/index.html

That said, because of all of the optional components and custom CRDs that extend the list of APIs, you should also learn how to access the API definitions via `oc api-resources` abd `oc explain`: this will list the APIs available on your particular cluster.